# Select Item Error

Tags: asp.net

i try to write a code when select the values, the status will auto change , but when i link the values with DB, it show out the Error, kindly ,advise, thank you.

[image]

```
private void SelectStatus()

    {
        WMWTLocator.Items.Clear();
        WMWTStatus.Text = "";

        string selectSQL = "SELECT STATUS_ID_SYS,STATUS_ID,STATUS_DESC FROM [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[IMS_STATUS_ID] WHERE STATUS_ID_SYS = 'WM' AND STATUS_ID = '" + WMWTLocator.SelectedItem.Value + "' ";


        try
        {
            con.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {


                ListItem newItem = new ListItem();
                WMWTStatus.Text = reader["STATUS_DESC"].ToString();
                newItem.Text = reader["STATUS_ID"].ToString();
                newItem.Value = reader["STATUS_ID"].ToString();
                WMWTLocator.Items.Add(newItem);

            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            lblResults.Text = "Error reading list of Transaction Status. ";
            lblResults.Text += err.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: try WMWTLocator.SelectedValue

Comment: Too localized (this only helps you, nobody else) and duplicate. Search the web or this site for the error, understand when you can get it and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking what is the value in the SelectedItem.Value?
I hope it is not coming out to be a null value, please make a check before executing the same, also check the same for all the parameters you are passing in the sql statement.

```
if(WMWTLocator.SelectedItem.Value!=null)
{
 //your query
}
```